# Cognito Customise Messages and Include User Attributes

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-java-sdk, amazon-cognito

We are running a Spring based project with Cognito as the identification service.

We have a project requirement to customise the *verification email* and *invitation email* for users in a Cognito user pool. (See [`here for the AWS doc`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-settings-message-customizations.html#cognito-user-pool-settings-ses-authorization-to-send-email))

Default verification message:

> Your verification code is {####}.

Default invitation message:

> Your username is {username} and temporary password is {####}.

We would like to include the `email`, `phone_number` and `name` user attributes into these emails. Is it possible to do this? I have searched the docs with no avail - and is really in need of some advice.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue.

Comment: Sort of! Sadly AWS do not allow to use any other attributes :(

Answer (score 1):

Update: I think the correct way to do this is to use `Custom Message` Cognito Lambda trigger (need to implement a function). Then you can have access to all the `userAttributes`.

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html